# Difference between position of redirection (2>/dev/null) in linux bash command

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

What‘s the difference between position of redirection in the following commands?

current user don't have permission write to `/test.txt`, **why the `2>/dev/null` NOT working in the second command `echo "hello" > /test.txt 2>/dev/null`？** it's still print the error message `bash: /test.txt: Permission denied`.

1. `echo "hello" > /test.txt`
2. `echo "hello" > /test.txt 2>/dev/null`
3. `echo 2>/dev/null "hello" > /test.txt`
4. `2>/dev/null echo "hello" > /test.txt`

```bash
$ 
$ echo "hello" > /test.txt
bash: /test.txt: Permission denied
$ 
$ echo "hello" > /test.txt 2>/dev/null
bash: /test.txt: Permission denied
$ 
$ echo 2>/dev/null "hello" > /test.txt
$ 
$ 2>/dev/null echo "hello" > /test.txt
$ 
$ whoami
sysadmin
$ 
$ type echo
echo is a shell builtin
$ 
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.2.2(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
$
```

[try in bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xpwh.png)

Comment: Because `bash: /test.txt: Permission denied` is printed by bash. Its stderr is connected to a terminal. Bash is opening `/test.txt`, not `echo`.

Comment: @LMC Why do you think it's from right to left? Run `strace -e openat sh -c 'echo 2>/dev/null > /test.txt'`. You'll see `/dev/null` is opened first, then attempt to open `/test`.

Comment: @LMC should be [from left to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvtJF.png).

Comment: Left to right, correct. By right to left I meant [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/860169)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. echo "hello" > /test.txt

Bash tries to open file `/test.txt` and reports error to descriptor 2 (stderr).

> 2. echo "hello" > /test.txt 2>/dev/null

Bash tries to open file `/test.txt` and reports error to descriptor 2 (stderr).

> 3. echo 2>/dev/null "hello" > /test.txt

Bash opens `/dev/null`, assigns descriptor 2 to refer to `/dev/null`, tries to open `/test.txt` and reports error to descripor 2 (`/dev/null`)

> 4. 2>/dev/null echo "hello" > /test.txt

The same as 3.

> why the `2>/dev/null` NOT working in the second command

Because the error message is printed before descriptor 2 is redirected to `/dev/null`.